# Specialize on functor return type

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I have the following type signature for a templated member function, which accepts a generic Functor (parameterless) as its sole argument and returns a Container type based on the return-type of the functor:

```
template <typename Func,
          typename Traits = funcTraits<Func>,
          typename R = typename Traits::resultType >
Container<R> spawn(Func call);
```

I am looking to create a specialisation of this function for Functors which have a void return type, something along the lines of:

```
template <typename Func,
          typename Traits = funcTraits<Func>,
          typename Traits::resultType == void >
Container<void> spawn(Func call);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specialize function templates.

You can however use SFINAE to set the return types. The standard one:

```
template <typename Func,
          typename Traits = funcTraits<Func>,
          typename R = typename Traits::resultType >
typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_void<R>::value,
    Container<R>
>::type
spawn(Func call);
```

And the `void` one:

```
template <typename Func,
          typename Traits = funcTraits<Func>,
          typename R = typename Traits::resultType >
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_void<R>::value,
    Container<void>
>::type
spawn(Func call);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot partial specialize a function, but you can with struct:

```
namespace detail
{

    template <typename Func, typename Traits, typename R>
    struct impl
    {
        Container<R> operator() (Func call) { /*Default implementation*/ }
    };

    template <typename Func, typename Traits>
    struct impl<Func, Traits, void>
    {
        Container<void> operator() (Func call) { /*specialization*/ }
    };

}


template <typename Func,
          typename Traits = funcTraits<Func>,
          typename R = typename Traits::resultType >
auto spawn(Func call) { return detail::impl<Func, Traits, R>{}(call); }
```